# Draggable from inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have one question and I can't find an answer for this...
I have the follow code:

Style:

```
<style>
  #out{ width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid red;}
  #test{ height:20px; widht: 100%; background-color:red; margin: 0;}
</style>
```

JS:

```
 $(function() {
  $( "#out" ).draggable();
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="out" class="ui-widget-content">
    <div id="test">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code I can dragg my div with id "out".
But what I want is that div with id "out" only be draggable when I'm dragg the inside div with id "test". To give an idea I want do the same efect that Windows window, only be draggable when u dragg top bar.

I already tested with jquery

```
$("test").focus(function(){
  $(this).parent().draggable();
});
```

But doesn't works...

Someone know what can I do?
Alot thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use handle option:

```
 $( "#out" ).draggable({ handle: "#test" });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gzk3ov06/

Comment: I'm ussing: "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" and "//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" but it doesn't works on local =/

Comment: Au... awesome... I was think that it works without http, now working fine.